# I see data in MongoDB collection but [object][object] is being displayed on the frontend

Tags: angular, mongodb

My data in MongoDB is structured like this:
Object.comment.Value

When I add '{{comment}}' to call from Mongo the following is displayed on the interface (see screen grab) instead of the real value that exist in the DB.

Any ideas? I feel like this is an obvious miss. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: {{comment?.Value}}..? Or {{comment | json}}

Comment: {{comment | json}} returns { "undefined": null }
{{comment?.Value}} returns nothing

Comment: Okay, so what comes back is not what you expect. Comment contains this  { "undefined": null } - which is an object really. What do you see in the network tab of your console and what does your http code looks like?

Comment: Looks like the content of Mongo *is* showing in the call when I inspect the Network tab.